# How inheritance works when method is CODEREF?

Tags: perl, mojolicious

In [Mojo::EventEmitter](https://metacpan.org/source/SRI/Mojolicious-7.08/lib/Mojo/EventEmitter.pm#L15) we have next line of code:

```
for my $cb (@$s) { $self->$cb(@_) }
```

Where `$cb` is `CODEREF` of callback.

Will there any difference and which are if I write:

```
for my $cb (@$s) { $cb->($self, @_) }
```

I suppose that inheritance will not work because of `$cb` is `CODEREF` as it works in case when `$cb` contains string with a method name.
So in this case rewritten code will work similar.

Do I understand all right or miss something?

Comment: There is a missing arrow operator `->` after `$cb`. It should be `$cb->($self, @_)`

Comment: @HåkonHægland Right -- if `$cb` is indeed a coderef, what isn't clear to me in the source.

Comment: @zdim The OP says that it is a `CODEREF`. So I trusted him.

Comment: @HåkonHægland Yes, by all means -- just meant to complement the statement since it makes a big difference.

Comment: `perl -E'my $f = sub { say "foo"; }; undef->$f()'`

Comment: @zdim Ok, I see that, but I couldn't imagine that he would use a string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When `$cb` is a code reference, inheritance is not checked. In fact, `$self` is not examined at all.

---

When `$cb` is a code reference,

```
$self->$cb(@_)
```

is functionally identical to

```
$cb->($self, @_)
```

That's why `$cb` should be obtained using `can`, which follows inheritance.

```
package Parent {
   sub new { bless({ @_ }, shift) }
   sub method { CORE::say("!"); }
}

package Child {
   our @ISA = 'Parent';
}

my $self = Child->new();
my $method_name = 'method';

my $cb = $self->can($method_name)
   or die("The object's class doesn't have method $method_name\n");

$self->$cb();
```

---

Note that some people use

```
my $f = "function_name";
undef->$f();
```

as an alternative to

```
my $f = "sub_name";
no strict qw( refs );
$f->();
```

Yet, it's quite inappropriate to use a method call to call a non-method, and this trick only works if the sub has no parameters. If you really have a problem with this (appropriate) use of `no strict`, you can you the following ([documented](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?strict)) trick:

```
my $f = "sub_name";
(\&$f)->();              # \&$f isn't subject to "use strict qw( refs );" checks
```

Comment: But is there a difference when `$cb` is string or CODEREF?

Comment: Inheritance is used when `$cb` is a string

Comment: May you add description for `$self::$cb()` scenario?

Comment: That isn't valid Perl. (`Scalar found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "$self::$cb"
        (Missing operator before $cb?)`)

Comment: do not understand why your so detailed answer was downvoted ((

Comment: @Eugen Konkov, *shrug*. It happens all the time. It might be that someone doesn't like some small little detail of the answer, and they'd rather downvote than to identify the problem or provide constructive criticism. It could be even be because of a typo that's already been fixed!